# Is it possible to update existing SQL Server 2014 Express with Advanced Services RTM to SP1 using the SP1 SQLEXPRADV_x64.exe?

Tags: windows, server-setup, sql-server-2014

I'm creating an installer that configures a SQL Server instance, and I'm trying to allow for it to update an existing installation if it is RTM. I tried with `/Action=Upgrade` with no success. Same story with `/Action=Install`.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

I needed to use this command line:

```
SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe /Action=Patch /InstanceName=[InstanceName] /Q /IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms
```

Also, you can use `/AllInstances` if you want to update all instances on the server.